# Install Internet Explorer 8 on windows 7

Tags: browser, internet-explorer

I recently installed Internet Explorer 9 but now want to revert back to Internet Explorer 8. How do I do it.

I uninstalled  IE9 but unlike Windows XP, I don't get  IE8 option.

Comment: Please explain downvote

Comment: So what option _do_ you get?

Comment: i just get a option to re-install ie9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit [MS IE8 Downloads](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-8) and download the version you require 32 or 64 bit

Comment: Please explain downvote Just did this on a  Win 7 system without issue.

Comment: He has IE9 installed, if he were to install IE8, if it lets him he will screw up his system.

Comment: The post indicates "I uninstalled IE9 but unlike Xp i dont get IE8 option"

Comment: That page doesn't (at least not as of Feb 2012) include a Windows 7 install.

Answer (score 4):

Uninstall IE9 from Programs and Features->Windows Updates.